# With python sh module, how to preserve combined stdout and stderr?

Tags: python, sh, stdout, stderr

Using the python `sh` module (http://amoffat.github.io/sh/index.html), how can I get the combined stdout and stderr, just like it would be if I had run the command on the terminal?

Comment: Since you've already found the documentation, you can easily find the answer in the [relevant section](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/special_arguments.html#err-to-out).

Comment: You call that easy? You have to know to browse for special kwargs (not exactly intuitive), and then you can find `_err` argument but you still have to know what values to assign to `_err` and `_out`, no examples given. Obviously, this question will become the new google result for anyone else ever searching for this, and now they have examples provided. It's better, and the -1 vote on this question is bullcrap.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is easy to read and well laid out with a [clear overview](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/reference.html). I didn't downvote, but I think you could certainly have shown more research effort in your question. As can been seen from the answer you got, there is a simple one-line solution. I have never used the `sh` module, but it took me less than a minute to find the same answer (although admitedly, it would have taken longer if I'd actually bothered to test it).

Comment: @ekhumoro, for what it's worth, I actually did find that documentation before posting here, but it was not clear that setting `_err` to something would achieve the desired result. The impression I got was that I could separately access file-like objects on `_err` and `_out` which would still give me two separate streams not combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example redirecting stdout and stderr from sh.ls(), to the process stdout and stderr.

```
import sh
import sys

sh.ls(_out=sys.stdout, _err=sys.stderr)
```

Stdout can also be captured into a string, per the following

```
import sh
import sys

s = sh.ls()
print( s )
```

You can also use:

```
sh.ls(_err_to_out = True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `_fg=True`, for example

```py
import sh

sh.ls("/", _fg=True)
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/steve/test.py
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
initrd.img
initrd.img.old
lib
lib64
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
vmlinuz
vmlinuz.old
```

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: when we use    _fg=True 
is it possible to get exit status of the process? I tried to capture that but it return None.